# When clicking on "add to cart " it shows popup , how to change text of that popup in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, popup

i want to change text in popup like "view cart and checkout" & "Not Now" texts to other text.

[image]

Where i will get this file so i will change text.

Comment: You can enable the template path hints and check the location of the files and change the text from there

Comment: popup comes when we click on "Add to cart " Button  and i think it come from Javascript. so hints is not helpful . <button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://104.236.232.134/totaltoys/10/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEwNC4yMzYuMjMyLjEzNC90b3RhbHRveXMvMTAvaW5kZXgucGhwL2Z1cm5pdHVyZS5odG1s/product/151/form_key/0wwPCpmUEi94bYNR/')"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>

Comment: is any one know where i will get the file?

Comment: find the text "not now" and "view cart and checkout" in all your files from editor

Comment: i searched but did't get file.